# Dataframe : rolling windows with "vlookup"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe like that :

```
VALUE   ATTRIBUTE
300         K
200         B
100         CC
150         D
100         EF
150         G
100         T
200         D
300         EF
400         T
350         G
400         F
550         FE
600         EF
700         D
650         F
400         EF
300         R
```

For each row, I want to perform a rolling-window (size = 5) in the next rows and return :

- max value
- related attribute

For example, the first row (300 K) has to return both :

- max value of 5 next rows => **200**
- related attribute => **B**

I'm performing a rolling windows in the future sequences (not in the previous one). Hence I'm shifting in my code.

I'm facing a problem since I'm able to return MAX_VALUE, but don't know how to return ATTRIBUTE related to max value. Below is the code i'm currently running :

```
df['MAX_VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].rolling(5).max().shift(-5)
```

**Do you have any suggestions to perform that function ?**

Expected results are:

```
VALUE   ATTRIBUTE   MAX_VALUE    ATTRIBUTE_MAX_VALUE
300         K       200      B
200         B       150      D
100         CC      200      D
150         D       300      EF
100         EF      400      T
150         G       400      T
100         T       400      T
200         D       550      FE
300         EF      600      EF
400         T       700      D
350         G       700      D
400         F       700      D
550         FE      700      D
600         EF      700      D
700         D       650      F
650         F       400      EF
400         EF      300      R
300         R       nan      nan
```

**Many thanks for your help !!**

Answer (score 0):

```
#creating two more columns: 'Max' and 'Attribute Max'
df['Max']=0
df['Attribute Max']=0
#running a for loop for finding rolling max and its attributes
for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
    df['Max'][i]=df['Value'][i+1:i+6].max()
# i+1 and i+6 are taken to consider from the next row till the next 5th row (6th row is excluded)
    df['Attribute Max'][i]=df['Attribute'][df['Value'][i+1:i+6].idxmax(axis=0)]
print(df)
```